# When running a validation through the bot framework how can I assure properties are mutable that belong to the class the validator is in?

Tags: javascript, typescript, botframework, this, this-pointer

I have come across this issues a few times now and I'd like to know if there is something I can do to mitigate the issue.

When using a waterfall dialog or dialog for that matter there are validators you can add to the dialog. These are associated in the class you are running the dialog against. Seemingly. But upon runtime the validator seems to be separate from class in which it is in.

Here is an example.

```js
 this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(SOME_PROMPT, this.validateSomething))
     .addDialog(new TextPrompt(SOME_PROMPT2, this.validateOtherthing))
```

And say your class has a property

`public mutableProperty1 = true;`

and in the validator

```js
private async validateSomething(context) Promise<any> {
    if (something happens here) {
       this.mutableProperty1 = false
       return true
    }
    return false
}
```

But that doesn't happen. When the retry prompt occurs the property is never mutated to the desired results.  Why is this and is there anything I can do to get it mutated as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is more of a TypeScript/JavaScript question than a bot question. I suspect the problem is that the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword in the function does not refer to the object you think it does. Whenever you pass a function as a value without calling it, it's usually a good idea to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the function to make sure `this` refers to the enclosing class instance.

```
this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(SOME_PROMPT, this.validateSomething.bind(this)))
    .addDialog(new TextPrompt(SOME_PROMPT2, this.validateOtherthing.bind(this)))
```

Comment: smh duh. lol thank you sir. sometimes when you use a framework so much you just think everything is in the box and forget the universe your're in.  Also, you're right it's a code question but I think it is a good bot question because of how the functionality of its use is a good tool to know.

Comment: Hey Kyle, I tried to implement this today and I am getting a TS error `Property 'someProerty' does not exist on type 'typeof xxxxxxxxxxnitialDialog'.ts(2339)` even though the property is there and available in the class

Comment: Well I haven't seen your code, so it's no easier for me to troubleshoot that than it is for you. Are you declaring your properties or just initializing them? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html